# C# AntiForgeryToken attribute causes StackOverflowException in mvc application

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, stack-overflow

I have created a antiforgery attribute class to decorate my `GenericBaseController` class:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class)]
public class ValidateAntiForgeryTokenAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        var request = filterContext.HttpContext.Request;

        //  Only validate POSTs
        if (request.HttpMethod == WebRequestMethods.Http.Post)
        {
            //  Ajax POSTs and normal form posts have to be treated differently when it comes
            //  to validating the AntiForgeryToken
            if (request.IsAjaxRequest())
            {
                var antiForgeryCookie = request.Cookies[AntiForgeryConfig.CookieName];

                var cookieValue = antiForgeryCookie != null
                    ? antiForgeryCookie.Value
                    : null;

                AntiForgery.Validate(cookieValue, request.Headers["__RequestVerificationToken"]);
            }
            else
            {
                new ValidateAntiForgeryTokenAttribute()
                    .OnAuthorization(filterContext);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

(reference link http://richiban.uk/2013/02/06/validating-net-mvc-4-anti-forgery-tokens-in-ajax-requests/ )

once a normal `POST` call in application is done (not ajax), I always get a `StackOverflowException`. 
Application without `ValidateAntiForgeryTokenAttribute` works fine.
If I debug the code inside this class, after a post request, flow keeps going trough the line

```
new ValidateAntiForgeryTokenAttribute()
    .OnAuthorization(filterContext);
```

infinitely. 
People in linked article assure that this implementation works, so I'm wondering why I'm getting this problem.
Is it really supposed to create a new `ValidateAntiForgeryTokenAttribute` when the request is not ajax ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Boiled down to the problem, your code is:

```
public class ValidateAntiForgeryTokenAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        if ( evaluateCondition() )
        {}
        else
        {
            new ValidateAntiForgeryTokenAttribute()
                .OnAuthorization(filterContext);
        }
    }
}
```

---

**The problem**

Your call is recursive in the `else` block:

- The class you are calling the method on is `ValidateAntiForgeryTokenAttribute`.
- In your `else` block you have

  ```
  new ValidateAntiForgeryTokenAttribute()
      .OnAuthorization(filterContext);
  ```

  which, given that the calling method is

  ```
  public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
  ```

  means that you will keep calling `OnAuthorization` (i.e. the same method) on new instances of a `ValidateAntiForgeryTokenAttribute`.

---

**Solution**

In the example you posted, the situation was slightly different - the name of the class is `ValidateAntiForgeryTokenOnAllPosts` whereas yours is `ValidateAntiForgeryTokenAttribute`, so the call is not recursive since the method is not calling itself with the same arguments.

You have three options - I'm not sure which is best for your situation (I'm thinking the first one):

- Change your Attribute name to `ValidateAntiForgeryTokenOnAllPosts` to match the name in [the example you posted](http://richiban.uk/2013/02/06/validating-net-mvc-4-anti-forgery-tokens-in-ajax-requests/).
- Explicitly state that you want [`System.Web.Mvc.ValidateAntiForgeryTokenAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.validateantiforgerytokenattribute) by changing the block to say

  ```
  new System.Web.Mvc.ValidateAntiForgeryTokenAttribute()
      .OnAuthorization(filterContext);
  ```
- Since you are overriding `ValidateAntiForgeryTokenAttribute`, you can call the base method, i.e.

  ```
  else
  {
      base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);
  }
  ```

Comment: thanks now it works fine... code was written by a collegue and I didn't noticed the change in attribute class name